# PhoneGap/Cordova on iOS: Get exact device hardware version (e.g. iPad 1 or iPad 2)

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

Looking at the [Cordova Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.platform), it seems that only some general information is available via the `device` object. However, I would like to find out not just the name of the device, but also its hardware version: For example if it's an iPad mini or iPad 2, iPhone 4 or 5...

Is there a built in way to do this with PhoneGap or must I resort to guessing the device by its user-agent and resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this code](https://gist.github.com/1323251) in your app to detect the device type.

I've just created [a gist with the plugin code](https://gist.github.com/4352031). Let me know if you have problem using it

If you have time could you have a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085761/cordova-ios-custom-plugin-handle-memory-warning) related to phonegap and memory management?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. But how would I implement this so that I can call it from JavaScript? As for your question: I don't have the slightest clue about native code, so I can't help you unfortunately. Have you tried the [PhoneGap Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/phonegap)?

Comment: if you can give me a contact I'll write you a phoneGap plugin to get this information. Maybe in the future you could help me who knows :)

Comment: My E-Mail is info@mobweb.ch - But perhaps you could also upload the plugin somewhere public so that people who find this thread via Google can benefit from it, too. :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Never heard back from you but I guess this answer is correct, even though I can't implement it myself. ;)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if you have problem using it

Comment: Nice, thank you. I will try soon (hopefully) and get back to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

In Cordova (PhoneGap) 2.3.0, this is possible without any plugins using `device.model`

> For all platforms, there is a new property called device.model — this returns the specific device model, e.g “iPad2,5″ (for other platforms, this returns what device.name used to return).

[Source](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Cordova%20iOS)

(From my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16175362/1549818))