# How to get iOS's Device Model (e.g. "iPhone3,1")?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, device, identifier

Is there a way to get the iOS's Device Model / Identifier like "iPhone3,1" within PhoneGap (JavaScript)?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, via the [Device API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device). You can access them via window.device.*. Here is a list of the properties:

device.name
device.cordova
device.platform
device.uuid
device.version

Comment: Nope, sorry. None of this properties gives back the Device Model. device.platform just gives back the type of device, not the actual model.

Comment: How about this plugin? https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/DeviceDetails

Answer (score 1):

In Cordova (PhoneGap) 2.3.0, this is possible without any plugins using `device.model`

> For all platforms, there is a new property called device.model — this returns the specific device model, e.g “iPad2,5″ (for other platforms, this returns what device.name used to return).

[Source](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Cordova%20iOS)

Answer (score 1):

"As of version 3.0, Cordova implements device-level APIs as plugins."

you must first install the plugin (from the project home directory): **cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device**

Here is a sample code for using it:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
        element.innerHTML = 'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +
                            'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
                            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                            'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

[PhoneGap Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_device_device.md.html)

When you have the plugin installed, you can than read the device model via: **window.device.model**

Don't forget to call it after **deviceready** event and don't forget to load the **cordova.js**
There is still a problem that the device reported is not accurate.
I tested it on various IOS devices and I get the following results:

**iPhone 4**  is reported as iPhone3,1

**iphone 5s** is reported as iPhone6,2

**iPhone 6 Plus** is reported as iPhone 7,1

**iPad 2** is reported as iPad3,3

I now investigate to understand what these values mean. 
If anyone has a clue I will be happy to hear.

Comment: The values are Apple Model identifiers. `iPhone6,2` is the iPhone 5S while `iPhone 6,1` is the iPhone 5. `iPhone 7,1` might be referring to either the iPhone 6 or the iPhone 6 Plus.